# no such column 'lastreferenceddate' on object in one org but not the other

Tags: managed-package, fields

I have an object thats part of our managed packaged. It has the standard field `lastreferenceddate` as well as `lastvieweddate` in a customer org but not in our packaging org. Any idea why this might be?

Comment: Are the two environments (group/professional/enterprise/unlimited) the same? It is possible to add custom fields to a managed package, so curious to see if you verified that these specific fields are part of the managed package itself, or ones that were created after the managed package custom object was created.

Comment: @TC Sutton These fields are salesforce native fields. They just don't exist in all orgs for some reason. They're both EE orgs.

Answer (score 1):

@Phil B ah that is right, the issue is that these specific fields were not added until summer of 2013, didn't make the connection that these were standard fields.

To configure default package versions for API calls:

> From Setup, click Develop | API. Click Configure Enterprise Package
>   Version Settings or Configure Partner Package Version Settings. These
>   links are only available if you have at least one managed package
>   installed in your organization. Select a Package Version for each of
>   your installed managed packages. If you are unsure which package
>   version to select, you should leave the default selection. Click Save.

You would want to make sure to set the API version to at least 28 or higher for these fields to display.

https://www.salesforce.com/developer/docs/api/Content/calls_package_versions.htm

Comment: Appreciate the help, but not sure this is it. The org that doesn't have the fields (one of my package dev orgs). I obviously don't have my package installed there. When I go to Develop -> API I see those 'Salesforce Connected Apps', 'Salesforce for Google AdWords' and another chatter one and the picklists for them are package versions not API versions.